# Calling a class in the Main()

Tags: java, class, applet, program-entry-point

I have written a class that is an applet and doesn't contain a `main()`.
Is there any possible way for me to just pass the entire class to `main` to run it because I can't call all the methods through `main`, I just use so many things it's impossible.

```
public static void main(String[] args){ }
public class Travel extends Applet implements MouseListener{
}
```

It seems Applets don't run `main()`.

Comment: You can include a main() method in an applet, so your applet can act as both an Application and an Applet.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but I can't figure out what needs to be in the main for the program to run. I can't do Travel t = new Travel(); and proceed to do all the methods because I'm not allowed to put in (MouseEvent)(boolean) Because I can't call the them the same way.

Answer (score 2):

This [hybrid demo](http://pscode.org/demo/hybrid/) can not only be run as either an applet or application, but be launched direct from the command line using the source in the applet viewer.

E.G.

```
prompt> javac HybridApplet.java
prompt> java HybridApplication // Note the 'Application'
prompt> appletviewer HybridApplet.java // Note the '.java'
```

Exiting the applet in the browser should redirect to the source.  It will have no effect in the applet viewer.  Applet viewer does not support showDocument(), unlike [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/), which does ;).

---

Edit:  Note though, that many things designed as applets leverage methods & classes useful to applets - getClip(), getDocumentBase()..

These are for convenience and mostly have equivalents in other non-applet classes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a main method in your applet class and instantiate it from within the main method.
If you really want to run the applet though, I suggest using the [appletviewer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html)